# Híndi text and font display problem

Tags: debian, fonts, special-characters

I'm starting a Híndi course and all non-English
(e.g., “Namastē” in Híndi alphabet) characters
don't appear correctly on my OS and programs. 
Is there any way to solve it? 
even just in my browsers? (Chrome and Firefox).

- I've already searched how to solve my problem on the internet,
  but found only Windows-only answers.
- I'm using Debian Stretch.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. 
I didn't have the font installed on my OS, so I did this:

- Downloaded a Hindi font (in my case, I've downloaded `Mangal_Regular.ttf`);

- Moved it from `~/Downloads` to `/usr/share/fonts/`:

  ```
  mv ~/Downloads/Mangal_Regular.ttf /usr/share/fonts/
  ```
- Rebuilt my font cache by doing           `fc-cache -f`
- Checked whether it has updated with `fc-list | grep Mangal`

It solved my problem:

[image: images of text displayed in Hindi]

Comment: The [task-hindi](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=task-hindi) packages also sound like a good starting point.

Comment: I didn't know about it, if u can provide an answer using it, I'll gladly mark it as a correct answer :D (I'll remove my font on OS and try with ur answer first)

Comment: I'm no expert on this topic, so you won't get an answer from me :)